# Comments to news, pages, photos etc. - how to Don't Repeat Yourself?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am writing simple content management system in ASP.NET MVC 4 + Entity Framework.
I want to have comments to news, pages, photos etc.

I have now PageComment model like the following:

```
public class PageComment
{
[Key]
public int CommentId { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Content { get; set; }

[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }

[Required]
public string AuthorName { get; set; }

public bool Approved { get; set; }

public bool Inappropriate { get; set; }

public int PageId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PageId")]
public Page Page { get; set; }
}
```

How to make universal comment model? I don't want to repeat for example: PageComment, PhotoComment, NewsComment, ArticleComment. This will be copy pasting the comment model.

Thanks in advance, David

Comment: Why don't you just name it `Comment` and use it for everything? Subclass it if you need specific functionality.

Comment: DRY means that all the common junk goes in the base class and the navigation(y?) properties are in child classes.

Comment: How to recognize page comments from news comments when I will have one model Comment? What will be better? Copying comment model or have one model with property for ex. CommentType and if 1 then news comment, if 2 then page comment?

Comment: I would recommend having a CommentType if they share the same exact properties and you need to know the type. If some properties differ, you can create subclasses of the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a string ContainerId property and then from the containing item, build up a unique ContainerId when a comment is made.

Something along these lines

- Pages
- - Page 1
- - - *ContainerId = 'pages-page1'*
- - - Photos
- - - - *ContainerId = 'pages-page1-photos'*
- - Page 2
- - - *ContainerId = 'pages-page2'*
- - - Photos 1
- - - - *ContainerId = 'pages-page2-photos-1'*
- - - Photos 2
- - - - *ContainerId = 'pages-page2-photos-2'*

When displaying comments, just filter by the ContainerId.